# How do I set Views Bulk Operations Fieldset Collapsed by default?

Tags: views

Using VBO, I am trying to set the Operations Fieldset to collapsed by default. Is there a setting to do this? or a theme override that I can use per view?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views_bulk_operations!views_bulk_operations.api.php/function/hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter/7)

```
<?php
function mymodule_views_bulk_operations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $vbo) {

 if($form['#form_id'] =='views_form_block_id'){

  $form['operations_fieldset']['#collapsed'] = TRUE;

 }

}
?>
```

Comment: You deserve the bounty for taking the time to give him the proper form ID, the more efficient function call, and the fieldset element's ID :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7):

```
<?php
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_bulk_operations') { // inspect your form in your browser to get the actual ID; it's in a hidden element at the bottom of the form.
    $form['operations_fieldset']['#collapsed'] = TRUE;
  }
}
?>
```

This assumes the fieldset's name is "operations_fieldset". You should install the devel module (drupal.org/project/devel) and then do a `dpm($form)` inside the `if()` statement in the code above to see what the form's elements are named.

More info on the 'fieldset' form element: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#fieldset

Answer (score 1):

I had to use this to get this to work in 7.x-3.2

```
<?php
function mymodule_views_bulk_operations_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $vbo) {
  if($form['#form_id'] =='views_form_[view_machine_name]_[view_display_type]'){
    $form['select']['#collapsible'] = TRUE;
    $form['select']['#collapsed'] = TRUE;
  }
}
?>
```

If you want it to apply to all bulk operations forms then just remove the $form['form_id'] condition.

Answer (score 0):

For all who googled this with a similar question: We have an [issue](https://drupal.org/node/1829210) to change the fieldset to **un**collapsible in VBO which might need some help.

Until we have that i rolled a [sandbox module](https://drupal.org/sandbox/axel.rutz/2087561) for this, based on Ryan G's snippet, but incorporating the [API changes](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views_bulk_operations!views_bulk_operations.module/function/views_bulk_operations_form/7) which happened since then.